# How to open ssdt Data Compare Tool form Visual Studio 2022

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I need to compare data between my source database and target database using SSDT's Data Compare tool in Visual Studio 2022. But I can't find any options that will open the Data Compare tool. I'm using SSDT version 17.2.40118.0

Comment: Tools Menu -> SQL -> Data Compare should work.

Comment: Peter - thanks for your reply. But, that menu option doesn't exist for me. I don't have a SQL menu option. I do have SQL Server menu option. But no Data Compare option.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or VS Code?  That Tools -> SQL option should be there for all of the "full" versions of Visual Studio.  For VS Code, you'd need the latest DB Project module installed for the data compare tool to show (I think).